# Angular $setPristine() not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use Angular's built-in form functions, specifically `setPristine()` to clear the form on user submit. My controller has access to `$scope.newForm` (my form) with all of its methods, but running `$scope.newForm.$setPristine()` isn't resetting the form fields.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="NewFormController">
    <h3>New Entry</h3>

    <form name="newForm" method="post" novalidate>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input name="name" type="text" ng-model="place.name"/>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Description</label>
           <textarea name="description" type="text" ng-model="place.description"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
           <label>Neighborhood</label>
           <input name="neighborhood" type="text" ng-model="place.neighborhood"/>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">    
            <label>Address</label> 
           <input name="location" type="text" ng-model="place.address"/>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submit(place)"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

And here is the controller where I call `setPristine()`:

```
app.controller('NewFormController', function($scope, $compile) {

    $scope.place = { 
        name: 'ExamplePlace', 
        description: 'This is a description!', 
        neighborhood: 'Manhattan', 
        address: '112 Street Place' 
    };

    $scope.submit = function(place) {
        $scope.newForm.$setPristine();
        $scope.newForm.$setUntouched();
    };

});
```

[Here is a working codepen](http://codepen.io/himmel/pen/yNWLPa) that reproduces my problem.

Note: I'm using Angular version 1.4.3.

Comment: You mean, ***isn't*** resetting.... yeah, `$setPristine` was not meant to do that - it just marks the form as `$pristine`. To reset, you need to clear/reset your view model, in your case: `$scope.place = {}`

Comment: Yes, "isn't". Thanks, I thought that setPristine() cleared the inputs as well.

Comment: well, no - it doesn't. It wouldn't even know *how*, because there are a number of way to "clear" - could be `""`, or `undefined` or something completely different for custom controls. So, to "clear", you modify the view model to whatever "clear" means, typically resetting to a new object works - which is how it is supposed to be

Comment: Gotcha - `$setPristine()` is helpful for form validation, but doesn't affect the view model variables declared in the input elements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$setPristine` only marks the form as being `$pristine`, which is useful for validation-driven expressions and CSS (e.g. `.ng-dirty`)

So, `$setPristine` does not clear the form's controls. In fact, it wouldn't even know *how* to do that. Consider, that to "clear" could mean different things to different models. "Clear" could mean `""`, or `undefined`, or `null`, or anything at all that a custom input control that works with `ngModel` could mean.

So, to properly clear the form is to modify the View Model that drives the form to whatever definition of "clear" it needs. In most cases - yours included - it is just a matter of setting the View Model to a new object:

```
$scope.submit = function(place) {
   $scope.newForm.$setPristine();
   $scope.newForm.$setUntouched();

   // clear the form
   $scope.place = {};
};
```

Comment: I dont understand the meaning of $scope.place. Could you tell me what that does and explain what it is exactly.

Comment: @Oliver, `$scope.place` is the model defined in the OP's question - it has not special meaning in Angular. The expression `$scope.place = {}` sets the model to a new object.