# Angular $setPristine is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

***Html :***

I'm using controller as syntax.

```
    <form name="occupantDetailForm" role="form" novalidate class="form-validation">
      <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label no-hint">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="LastName" ng-model="vm.occupantDetail.lastName" ng-class="{'edited':vm.occupantDetail.lastName}" maxlength="@OccupantDetail.MaxLength" required>
              <label>@L("LastName")</label>
       </div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary blue" ng-click="vm.saveOccupantDetail(occupantDetailForm)" ng-disabled="occupantDetailForm.$invalid"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> <span>@L("Save")</span></button>
    </form>
```

***JS :***

```
 vm.saveOccupantDetail = function (form) {
                    vm.occupantDetailForm = form;
                    createOrEditOccupantDetail();//create or edit 
                    vm.occupantDetail = {};
                    vm.occupantDetailForm.$setPristine();
                      }
```

***Q :*** I have tried many ways but it is not working ? When I use the `vm.occupantDetailForm.$setUntouched();` then it works fine.But then the problem is `Save` button is not being disabled.Could you tell me why ? When I use the `vm.occupantDetailForm.$setPristine();` only then it is not working at all.Why ? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried  occupantDetailForm.$invalid || occupentDetailForm.$dirty ?

Comment: Are you trying to reset the form?

Comment: @HristoGeorgiev Nope,Why should I use that ?

Answer (score 0):

`$setPristine` only marks your form as `$pristine` and to actually `reset` the form you need, set your `model` to a `new object`.

A better explanation is given here in the link:
[$setPristine not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32029889/angular-setpristine-not-working)

Below is some code which might help you:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="UserCtrl">
        <form name="user_form" novalidate>
            <input name="name" ng-model="user.name" placeholder="Name" required/>
            <button class="button" ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>     
        </form>
        <p>
            Pristine: {{user_form.$pristine}}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller Code:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

function UserCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.user = {};
        $scope.user.name = "";
        $scope.user_form.$setPristine();
        $scope.user = {};
    }  
}
```

A fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/p7e1nway/1/

**Update:**, can you try setting `$submitted` to false

```
$scope.occupantDetailForm.$setPristine();    
$scope.occupantDetailForm.$setUntouched(); 
$scope.occupantDetailForm.$submitted = false;
```

Comment: If you look at above code snippet I have done that.Here `vm.occupantDetail = {};`

Comment: I need to set the form into its initial state without any validation errors and etc..

Comment: The way you are setting it back to initial state is what i feel is causing you the problem... vm.occupantDetail = {};                   vm.occupantDetailForm.$setPristine();

Comment: I'm using `controller as syntax.`.Not like you have mentioned above.Thanks.

Comment: That's fine sampath, vm.yourobj = {} after $setPristine() would do the trick.

Comment: I have done that also.But same result.I can avoid this by using `vm.occupantDetailForm.$setUntouched();` but then `Save` button is not being disabled.It shows as enable even though no form data are there.Do you know why ? Thanks.

Comment: Can you try this below: $scope.occupantDetailForm.$setPristine();
      $scope.occupantDetailForm.$setUntouched();
      $scope.occupantDetailForm.$submitted = false; and check...

Comment: No difference :(  Still Save button is being enabled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106015/discussion-between-thalaivar-and-sampath).